# bootstrap how to make an icon on NavBar not disappearing when on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap to do my Navigation Bar. I have gone through some tutorials, but one thing which I cannot find is:

So my need is:
I want to have an Icon always showing up in the NavBar no matter it's on desktop or mobile.
So it looks like this pic:
[image]

But when I browse the page on a mobile, all navigation links disappeared and you have to click the hamburger icon in order to see them.

Here is my code:

```
  <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
<div className="container-fluid">
  <div className="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
      <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span className="icon-bar"></span>
      <span className="icon-bar"></span>
      <span className="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <div className="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><Link to="/sign-up">Sign Up</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/sign-in">Sign In</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/sign-out">Sign Out</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/my-stories">My Stories</Link></li>
      <li><Link to="/reviews">Reviews</Link></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem has been solved.

My intention was to use Bootstrap built-in css classes to solve this issue and here is how I write it without any hand-coded css:

```
    <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" />
    </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is bootstraps default, it hides big menu if window width is less then 768px, you should change css then, find class navbar and navbar default and change media queries

Answer (score 1):

You can use media query for mobile devices as shown below.

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}
```